# I am getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: execution reverted error while calling my smart contract methods using wb3js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3.py, infura, web3-providers

Here is my code

````
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2a6f2bf907594edfbe6343066c394df8"));
// web3.eth.handleRevert = true
var address = "0xCE67854ea017A7698EB1EE42683c6132cFba9420";
var abi = [
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "interfaceId",
                "type": "bytes4"
            }
        ],
        "name": "supportsInterface",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "name",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getApproved",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "approve",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "totalSupply",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "index",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tokenOfOwnerByIndex",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "safeTransferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "index",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tokenByIndex",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ownerOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "baseURI",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "balanceOf",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "symbol",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setApprovalForAll",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "name": "_data",
                "type": "bytes"
            }
        ],
        "name": "safeTransferFrom",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "tokenURI",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "isApprovedForAll",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "symbol",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "from",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Transfer",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "tokenId",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "Approval",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "owner",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "name": "operator",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "approved",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "name": "ApprovalForAll",
        "type": "event"
    }
];
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
// console.log(contract)
// contract.methods.name().call().then(console.log).catch((e)=>{
//     console.log("Error: ",e)
// }); //this command is working
contract.methods.symbol().call().then(console.log)```
Please help me
````

Comment: You should also post ONLY the code relevant to the actual problem, not your entire program.

Comment: You should also post ALL the code relevant to the actual problem, for example, since the contract that address is not verified on etherscan, you should show its actual source code (that is, the part relevant to the function that you are trying to call on it).

Comment: Okay sorry guys, I will try to figure it out and then i will get back with the specific issue. Thank you for the guidance :)

Comment: Wait, I have an answer for you.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. It works for a simple contract but as i am using an ERC721 contract, It was throwing an error. I will try it again and debug more before posting anything again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function `symbol()` in the contract at the specified address on Rinkeby.

How do I know?

Because the corresponding [function selector](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.12/abi-spec.html#function-selector) does not exist in the bytecode at that address.

Here is a short script (based on your script) to prove it:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2a6f2bf907594edfbe6343066c394df8"));
const address = "0xCE67854ea017A7698EB1EE42683c6132cFba9420";
const selector = Web3.utils.keccak256("symbol()").slice(2, 10);
web3.eth.getCode(address).then(function(bytecode) { 
    if (bytecode.includes(selector))
        console.log("function is in the contract");
    else
        console.log("function is not in the contract");
});
```

When running this script, the printout is `function is not in the contract`.

Comment: Thank you, this script was very helpful. Means a lot :)